# Using if and find together

Tags: bash, find, directory

I'm trying to write a script that echos "success" if it finds .trc files older than 5 days in a directory. However I'm getting a full_path_trace': No such file or directory error even though my directory exists. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
full_path_trace='/u01/app/oracle/myfolder/trace'
if [[ -n $(find "full_path_trace" -name "*.trc" -mtime +5) ]]
 then
   echo "success!"
else

  echo "fail"
fi
```

Comment: You define full_path_trace but you don't use it. You need a `$` between the first double quote and `full_path_trace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the a `$` in front of the variable. Here, I'd do:

```
if find "$full_path_trace" -name '*.trc' -mtime +5 -print -quit |
   grep -q '^'; then
  echo 'Success!'
else
  echo >&2 fail
fi
```

Drop the `-quit` if your `find` doesn't support it.

`grep -q` returns true as soon as a line is found in the input.

`-quit` would cause `find` to exit upon the first match and stop searching for more. Without `-quit`, `grep` would quit after reading the first line and would eventually cause `find` to exit early if there are a lot of other files.